# HTTP iframe on HTTPS page

Tags: http, iframe, https

I have a simple question, but can't find the answer that I'm looking for.

Is a http iframe that's loaded on a secure https page also secured?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not automatically, you should verify if the src of your iframe is connecting via https or not:

```
<iframe src="http://www.example.com"></iframe>
```

your iframe doesn't extend the https access from principal page.

Answer (score 1):

A iframe with http source will not be displayed on a https website as it's considered mixed content and browsers like Chrome will block the content with the following message:

> Mixed Content: The page at '**your website**' was loaded over HTTPS,
>   but requested an insecure resource '**iframe http source** '. This
>   request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.

So far I have not seen a solution to allow mixed content. 
There has been a solution for Firefox which is based on redirecting the iframe source via another website that is hosted on the HTTPS Domain.